# Kubernetes - Minikube enable ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to enable ingress in minikube with the following command.

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Getting the below error,

> [getting command runner: getting ssh client for bootstrapper: Error
>   dialing tcp via ssh client: ssh: handshake failed: EOF]

List command is working fine. Is there anything missing here?

```
minikube addons list

- addon-manager: enabled
- coredns: disabled
- dashboard: enabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- heapster: disabled
- ingress: disabled
- kube-dns: enabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling minikube fixed the issue